# Using autohotkey with a gamepad

Tags: autohotkey, game-controller

I can map buttons on a gamepad like this:

```
Joy2::
Send {Up down}  ; Hold down the left-arrow key.
KeyWait Joy2  ; Wait for the user to release the joystick button.
Send {Up up}  ; Release the left-arrow key.
return
```

However I want to remap the directional pad to do the same thing instead.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Auothotkey Joystick axis tutorial;
http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/KeyList.htm#Joystick

Or you could use KeyHistory to find what the Autoit name of the key is;

key_detect.ahk:

```
!k::
#InstallKeybdHook
KeyHistory
return
```

Run, press Alt+K. Brings up list of keys detected.